# reset all inputs on angular 2 parent and child component

Tags: angular

I'm a Angular 2 newbie. After learning Angular 2, I made a demo app use parent and child component. The view of parent component has form element and a few inputs and view of child component has other inputs.
This is my view of parent component

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"><div class="field clearfix w50" >
                    <label>Destination <span class="note">*</span></label>
                    <div [class.has-error]="is_draft_validated && !destination.value">
                        <input type="text" name="destination" [(ngModel)]="TRequest.destination" #destination="ngModel" class="form-control">
                        <span *ngIf="is_draft_validated && !destination.value" class="error">{{ 'VALIDATE.required' | translate }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div><payment-dietary *ngIf="TRequest.m_menu_request_id==9" [clear]="is_clear" [dietary]="TRequestDietary"></payment-dietary><button class="btn btn-style btn-style-special btn-chart" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>&nbsp;Save
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-style btn-clear" (click)="onClear(f)">
                        <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>&nbsp;Reset
                    </button></form>
```

And my view of child component

```
<div class="field clearfix w100">
        <label>Participant Name <span class="note">*</span></label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="participant_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Item.participant_name" #participant_name="ngModel" [class.ng-invalid]="participant_name?.dirty && !participant_name.value">
            <span *ngIf="participant_name?.dirty && !participant_name.value" class="error">{{ 'VALIDATE.required' | translate }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field clearfix w50">
        <label>Participant Number <span class="note">*</span></label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="participant_num" class="form-control numeric" [(ngModel)]="Item.participant_num" (keyup)="Item.participant_num = $event.target.value" #participant_num="ngModel" [class.ng-invalid]="(participant_num?.dirty || participant_num?.touched) && !participant_num.value && !clear" id="form_participant_num">
            <span *ngIf="(participant_num?.dirty || participant_num?.touched) && !participant_num.value" class="error">{{ 'VALIDATE.required' | translate }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And child component code

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TRequestDietary } from '../../../../models';

@Component({
    selector: 'payment-dietary',
    templateUrl: './payment-dietary-form.component.html',
})

export class PaymentDietaryFormComponent{
    @Input('dietary') Item: TRequestDietary;
    @Input() clear: boolean;
}
```

When I press button to reset form, I can only reset input on view of parent but can not reset inputs on view of child component. This is the code reset form

```
onClear(form: NgForm){
form.reset();
}
```

I don't know how to reset inputs on child component. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a child-parent combination then use a class of  "TRequest" in parent. like

At parent Class define

```
public TRequest : TREQUEST;
```

And create a TREQUEST type class

```
class TREQUEST{
public Prop1:string ="";
public Prop2:number =null;
}
```

use it in templates and also in child.
When need to reset

```
this.TRequest = new TREQUEST();
```

This new will reset your model by creating new instances.

Answer (score 1):

You have 'clear' boolean value sent to the child component.
You could use [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes)

Change in parent component:

```
onClear(form: NgForm){
this.is_clear=true;
form.reset();
}
```

You toggle the `isClear` of the child component in parent function. This is set in the parent template.

and in child component,

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
 for (let propName in changes) {
if(propName==clear){
     //check for false to true and reset
}
}
}
```

`ngOnChanges` lifecyclehook is called when changes are detected in the component. Here you can detect the change of `isClear` variable from false value to true and reset the form in the child.

Comment: Can you give some explanation?